# Uncertainty propagation and confidence intervals calculation using python scipy.curvefit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a function using scipy.optimize.curve_fit.
I am implementing a fitting of data with the sum of 3 gaussians.

Here is the data that must be fit.

[image: Initial data for fitting]

I need to estimate the parameters of each Gaussian and the errors of calculation of these parameters.
So I need to calculate the uncertainty of the fitting procedure and propagate this data to show a confidence interval for the modelled data.

Is it possible to do it using the error of parameters calculated using np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov_3gauss))? I saw it here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

What approach should I use to propagate the parameters uncertainties and calc the uncertainty bands for the fitting?

Here is the code I have implemented for fitting.

```
# Initial data for fitting
x_array = np.array(sep_df.E)
y_array_3gauss = np.array(sep_df.exp_cs)

def _1gaussian(x, amp1,cen1,sigma1,offset):
    return amp1*(1/(sigma1*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x-cen1)/sigma1)**2)))+offset

def _3gaussian(x, amp1,cen1,sigma1,amp2,cen2,sigma2,amp3,cen3,sigma3,offset):
    return _1gaussian(x, amp1,cen1,sigma1,offset=0) + \
        _1gaussian(x, amp2,cen2,sigma2,offset=0) + \
           _1gaussian(x, amp3,cen3,sigma3,offset=0) + offset

#initial_guesses for Gaussians
amp1 = 100 #max value without an offset (!)
cen1 = 140 # position of a center
sigma1 = 1 # sd of a gaussian, can be calculated approx. as  HWHM / 2.355 

amp2 = 32
cen2 = 157
sigma2 = 1

amp3 = 17.5
cen3 = 171.5
sigma3 = 1

offset_initial_guess = y_array_3gauss.mean()

p0=[amp1, cen1, sigma1, 
amp2, cen2, sigma2, 
amp3, cen3, sigma3, 
offset_initial_guess]

# using a scipy.optimize.curve_fit for parameters Estimation
popt_3gauss, pcov_3gauss = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(_3gaussian, x_array, y_array_3gauss, p0=p0)
perr_3gauss = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov_3gauss)) # errors (??)

print('Popt_3 gauss')
print(popt_3gauss)

i=0
for param in popt_3gauss:
    print(f'Guess: {p0[i]} -> value: {param} (+/-) {perr_3gauss[i]}')
    i+=1

pars_1 = np.append(popt_3gauss[0:3], popt_3gauss[9])
pars_2 = np.append(popt_3gauss[3:6], popt_3gauss[9])
pars_3 = np.append(popt_3gauss[6:9], popt_3gauss[9])

#calculating the separate Gaussians
gauss_peak_1 = _1gaussian(x_array, *pars_1)
gauss_peak_2 = _1gaussian(x_array, *pars_2)
gauss_peak_3 = _1gaussian(x_array, *pars_3)
```

it fits the data with some errors.
I don't really understand why my Gaussian pulses look so weird, but it's not the question for now.

Here is the output for model parameters:

```
Guess: 100 -> value: 19.921886501569567 (+/-) 0.18211089486661997
Guess: 140 -> value: 140.8226385680359 (+/-) 0.0009978640529532633
Guess: 1 -> value: 0.07977753969265024 (+/-) 0.0008591843799752477
Guess: 32 -> value: 5.8061836613068865 (+/-) 0.21223980806115864
Guess: 157 -> value: 157.24985139555835 (+/-) 0.005092072398387486
Guess: 1 -> value: 0.08218041022663795 (+/-) 0.0034588647851462877
Guess: 17.5 -> value: 4.183133300983996 (+/-) 0.2522036049333162
Guess: 171.5 -> value: 171.47025791173272 (+/-) 0.008818904590601183
Guess: 1 -> value: 0.11713718144344663 (+/-) 0.008042004990244404
Guess: 4.743919339218138 -> value: 4.016878986311514 (+/-) 0.04473028381895628
```

And fitting results:
[image: Fitting results for 3 pulses]

For the first pulse using zoom to scale the image:

[image: Fitting results for the first peak]

And with resampled scale for E-axis:

[image: Resampled scale to view the beauty of Gaussians :)]

Comment: Shape of your peak is sampled on your data. Just resample with finer resolution and Gaussian curves will look Bell shaped.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @jlandercy. Yes, I understand this. I forgot to add figures with different sampling. I will do the update. The problem is that fitting peaks have larger amplitudes and differ from the data I have, significantly.

Answer (score 0):

One may calculate the uncertainty bands using strong analytical approach (if the function is known, like in my case). But it's pretty hard to obtain all the derivatives and even if it's possible a lot of calculations must be done for that.

I havr tried to use simplified approach. I used Monte Carlo technique.
I have repeatedly randomly sampled the values of errors for estimated parameters and calculated overal fitting results.

So I have calculated the function results for all randomly-noised parameters and got a large dataset of results.

Then I have used only the the max and min values of calculated results I have got - to obtain numerical values of bounds.

The result is presented below.
[image: result and the confidence band for one pulse]